# python script to .deb ubuntu package to install a daemon

Tags: ubuntu, python-2.7, daemon, deb, upstart

I have a python script which runs a daemon-like service, now I created the python package. I created a .deb package from there but I want the script to be run with upstart, but I can't mange to write the files in the /etc/init ubuntu folder automatically when .deb package is installed so that my daemon doesn't have to be started manually on reboot. I don't know if I explained this well, but I don't know how to explain it better...

what I have:
python_script.py ->runs a python-daemon

python_script.tar.gz -> python package

what I need:

python.deb -> which install the python script and sets up the upstart for my python scrip so that it runs as a service/daemon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look for the [debian packaging doc for python](http://wiki.debian.org/Python/Packaging), other that can be useful is the [stdeb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb) tool, a Python to Debian source package conversion utility.

For running it as a daemon you need to create a init.d script (you can see how to [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/28), and [here](http://werxltd.com/wp/2012/01/05/simple-init-d-script-template/) a more complete example), you can add the init.d script in the package and then call "update-rc.d myscript defaults" from the postinst script of the python.deb and call "update-rc.d -f myscript remove" from the prerm script.

Comment: well I know hoe to create the package, my problem is that normally packages don't istall stuff in upstart, my problem is "how to create a custom install to set a python script as an upstarted daemon"...

Comment: nice! we are getting closer! in which part of the script should I move the init.d file in the package to etc/init.d? How? How should I edit the postinst script to  run "update-rc.d myscript defaults"? How should I compile the package with a custom postinst? as long as `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc` overwrites the postinst??

Comment: I can change the .deb manually even if it gives md5 checksum error... but anyhow the real problem is that when I try to move the file from the package bash doesn't find the file! I tried to find the working directory with $PWD and  DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )" but nothing !!

Comment: I almost got there with the files and everything, the only problem is that when I change manually the deb package the installer shows this warning : Error bad quality package. how can compile my custom deb without running in this trouble

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Ubuntu standard way to create deb package all you need to do is to place package-name.upstart in debian folder.

> dh_installinit is a debhelper program that is responsible for
>          installing upstart job files or init scripts with associated defaults
>          files into package build directories, and in the former case providing
>          compatibility handling for non-upstart systems.

See [dh_installinit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dh_installinit.1.html).

I find building a [Debian package from Bazaar branch](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/builddeb-plugin.html) to be the easiest way to create deb package.

See [Packaging New Software](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/packaging-new-software.html) as well.

I used such approach to create Gearman Job Server set of packages. Placing gearman-job-server.upstart was sufficient.

Comment: I managed to change all the files I needed to setup the init and everything by hand, but now even if I rebuilt the md5checksum file using the command `sudo find . -type f ! -regex '.*.hg.*' ! -regex '.*?debian-binary.*' ! -regex '.*?DEBIAN.*' -printf '%P ' | xargs md5sum > DEBIAN/md5sums` I get this warning when installing the package 'shack': The package is of bad quality; Lintian check results for /../dist/deb_dist/shack-0.1.1-new.deb:
E: python-shack: control-file-has-bad-permissions md5sums 0664 != 0644
E: python-shack: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid debian/ 1000/1000